# Update content to add additional text in field, only. SQL

Tags: sql, sql-update

I'm working in SQL language. I have this title stored in the database (a forum)

```
 the door is wide open for musicians
```

When I close the topic, I need to add up the next text to the title

```
 [CLOSED TOPIC]
```

in order it to shows up like this

```
[CLOSED TOPIC]  the door is wide open for musicians
```

What I do is

```
UPDATE posts
SET closed = 1,
    title = CONCAT('[CLOSED TOPIC] ', 'title')  
WHERE id_post = :id_post
LIMIT 1
```

And the post returns this

```
   [CLOSED TOPIC]  title
```

instead of this

```
   [CLOSED TOPIC]  the door is wide open for musicians
```

What am I doing wrong? Thank you.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (Standard SQL has not LIMIT for UPDATE, or at all.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`CONCAT('[CLOSED TOPIC] ','title')` concatenates string literals.
`CONCAT('[CLOSED TOPIC] ',title)` will concatenates string literal `'[CLOSED TOPIC] '` and column value `title`.